# Windows doesn't find wireless JBL headset

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

[This is a copy of this Microsoft Community question. As the asnwer was quite canned, I'd like to ask a better community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/jbl-headphones-are-not-showing-up/bcfcccf3-620f-4fe2-9b5d-5f7400e0269b)

Good evening, and my merriest wishes for a happy 2019

I recently bought a wirelsess JBL headset, model T460BT, and I wanted to connect it to my freshly-resetted HP G3 250 laptop-notebook. Little did I know, Windows refused to even find the device while on the Add Devices pane. Some of the remedies I tried are:

1. Restarting my laptop
2. Restarting the headset
3. Restarting any service that contained `Bluetooth` in its name
4. Running the Bluetooth troubleshooter
5. Running the Devices and Hardware troubleshooter
6. Reinstalled the most recent drivers from [HP's website](https://support.hp.com/gr-el/drivers/selfservice/hp-250-g3-notebook-pc/6732462 (warning: site in greek) for sound & networking
7. Disabling my bluetooth adapter
8. **Uninstalling** my bluetoth adapter
   All with no avail.

I am considering buying a new USB Bluetooth adapter, but I wish to make sure that the one I currently have is completely trash before shelling out money to get a new one

**Technical Details (in case they help)**

- OS: Windows 10 Home
- Version: 1803
- Build #: 17137.472

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Do any other bluetooth devices work correctly with your PC? Also can you please try to pair your headset with your phone or other computer, does it work? It is possible that the headset cannot be paired with your bluetooth adapter.

Comment: The headphone connect with my phone (Huawei P8 Lite). I haven't really tried anything else, except some wireless earbuds in... 2016 I think (its a rather old computer)

Comment: What's the bluetooth adapter you have in your PC? I would suggest trying different adapter to pair your headphones with, but it's not guaranteed to work. I think that there's nothing wrong with your headphones or your computer. Maybe the adapter uses different bluetooth version or something like that.

Comment: `Mediatek Bluetooth Adapter`, it claims to be. We have no other (pc-friendly) Bluetooth adapter at home